# iOSで本番環境のみプッシュ通知が届かない

Tags: ios, java, objective-c, push-notification

アプリはObjective-Cでの実装で、
サーバー側ではAPNsのライブラリにjavaPNS_2.2.jarを使用しています。

デバッグ環境、本番環境の差異は次の通りです。
デバッグ環境
　iOS Apple Push Notification service SSL(Sandbox)
　上記の証明書から.p12ファイルを作りサーバーに配置
本番環境
　Apple Push Notification service SSL(Sandbox & Production)
　上記の証明書から.p12ファイルを作りサーバーに配置

表題の通りデバッグ環境ではiOS12,13の端末共に届きますが、
本番環境ではどちらの端末にも届かない状態です。

証明書かProvisioningProfile辺りの問題かと思われるのですが、
詳細が見当がつきません。
原因が分かる方、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。
javaPNSで送るデバイストークンの形式が不正なものがあると
デバッグ環境でもプッシュ通知の送信に失敗することを確認しました。